# What are some real world uses for function.toString()?

Tags: javascript

I've noticed in JavaScript that if you define a function, say `myfunction()`, and then call `myfunction.toString()`, you get the text of the source for that function. Are there any interesting/real world uses of this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, you can use it to easily redefine a function:

```
function x() { alert('asdf'); }
eval(x.toString().replace('asdf','hello'));
x();
```

This will alert the string "hello" instead of the string "asdf".

This may be useful. On the other hand, self modifying code is often frowned upon because of the difficulty to maintain it...

Comment: +1 for showing `eval` as the complement of `toString`. It doesn't have to be self modifying - you can change or copy code from different sources (when there isn't a better interface).

Comment: This isn't guaranteed to work though. For example, certain browsers will always show strings within a function wrapped in double-quotes, even if they were single-quoted in the source. This means that any attempt to evaluate the result of fn.toString() will cause a syntax error if one of those strings contains a double-quote. I'm pretty sure this is a spec violation by those browsers, but it still means that this technique can't be used in the real world :-(

Comment: note that "private" variables of self invoked functions are still safe from this type of hooliganism. ie var x = function () { var a = 'asdf'; return {doit:function(){alert(a)}}}(); < there is no way to change "a" in this case, only the "public" returned "doit" function.

Answer (score 15):

This is an old question, but here are my 2 cents.

Using node.js, this becomes useful for creating functions on the serverside which are then embedded into a page and sent to the client.

For example, the dot.js template engine works by first compiling templates into a function, which can then be executed to generate the HTML code.

eg:

```
var compiled = dot.compile("<h1>{{=it.header}}</h1>");
var html_output = compiled({header: "hello world"});
```

So, if we want to make use of templates in the client without each client having to compile them first, we can serve them a page containing the evaluated result of:

```
"var compiled = " + dot.compile("<h1>{{=it.header}}</h1>").toString();
```

which will then provide a "compiled" function client-side, for use compiling data such as that sent from ajax requests into HTML client-side.

Answer (score 10):

I've used it to automatically generate named-parameter versions of functions. For example, if you have a function

```
function f(a, b, c) {
    return a * b + c;
}
```

you can extract the parameter names from `f.toString()` and use it to generate a function that you can call like this:

```
namedParametersF({ a: 2, b: 3, c: 4}); // f(2, 3, 4);
```

Here's an implementation of this idea:

```
// Get an array of parameter names from a function
Function.parameters = function(f) {
    // Find the parameter list in f.toString()
    var m = /function[^\(]*\(([^\)]*)\)/.exec(f.toString());
    if (!m) {
        throw new TypeError("Invalid function in parameters");
    }

    var params = m[1].split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        // trim possible spaces
        params[i] = params[i].replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '');
    }
    return params;
};

// Convert f to a function that accepts named parameters
Function.withNamedParameters = function(f) {
    var params = Function.parameters(f);
    return function(args) {
        var argsArray = new Array(params.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            argsArray[i] = args[params[i]];
        }
        return f.apply(this, argsArray);
    };
};
```

I have a slightly more flexible implementation of this that can go the other direction (`Function.withPositionalParameters`) on GitHub: http://gist.github.com/132782.

Answer (score 7):

Elaborating on the [idea raised above by James Westgate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17042496/1323970), here's an example of a use of `toString()` to create, dispatch & receive a web worker:

```
/*
 * @param fun the function to carry out in the web worker
 * @param mes the message to send to the web worker
 * @param com the function to do on completion
 * creates, dispatches & receives a web worker
 */
function wor(fun, mes, com) {
   var wor = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([
         'self.onmessage = ' + fun.toString()], {
         type: 'application/javascript'
   })));       
   wor.postMessage(mes);
   wor.onmessage = com;
}
```

By turning the function into a string we can use it to so create a function in an object URL, which is then parsed & executed on receiving data.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is essentially used for debugging purposes...

Comment: Can you give some examples of how you might use it for debugging purposes?

Comment: It happened to me one time: A call to one of my Javascript function didn't do what I was expecting. Using this toString() trick helped me to understand that the function I called was not the one I wrote. Indeed, this function was defined twice (one time by me, another time in a third-party .js file), and of course, my function was not the one who was called...
But I must say that the call of the function.toString() is quite unusual...

Answer (score 4):

#### Multi-line strings in Javascript source.

As described in [this blog post by @tjanczuk](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2013/05/multi-line-strings-in-javascript-and.html), one of the massive inconveniences in Javascript is multi-line strings. But you can leverage `.toString()` and the syntax for multi-line comments (`/* ... */`) to produce the same results.

By using the [following function](https://gist.github.com/barneycarroll/5705383#file-uncomment-js):

```
function uncomment(fn){
  return fn.toString().split(/\/\*\n|\n\*\//g).slice(1,-1).join();
};
```

…you can then pass in multi-line comments in the following format:

```
var superString = uncomment(function(){/*
String line 1
String line 2
String line 3
*/});
```

In the original article, it was noted that `Function.toString()`'s behaviour is not standardised and therefore implementation-discrete — and the recommended usage was for Node.js (where the V8 interpreter can be relied on); however, [a Fiddle I wrote seems to work on every browser I have available to me](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/WPPYf/) (Chrome 27, Firefox 21, Opera 12, Internet Explorer 8).

Answer (score 3):

One real-world example is in [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), which uses this to determine the names of the arguments to methods in subclasses to see if it should do its special [superclass handling](http://prototypejs.org/api/class/create) stuff (which involves the special argument `$super`).

Comment: So basically, it can be used for reflection?

Comment: Basically, yeah, or even modification as shown by the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

CouchDb's view definitions take their `map` and `reduce` as strings. With `function.toString` you can write these functions as proper functions (so an IDE/syntax checker can help you), then convert them to strings when inserting them.

Comment: I use this to be able to unit test map and reduce functions. I then mock `emit`

Answer (score 3):

Angular JS uses this pattern to inject it's built-in services. All you need to do is use a service name (prefixed by "$") as a parameter to your function - for example: "$http".

[See the exact usage on Github.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/a26234f7183013e2fcc9b35377e181ad96dc9917/src/auto/injector.js#L54)

Answer (score 2):

I believe Visual Studio's Intellisense uses this to locate and parse optional [XML Code Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514138.aspx) for any such documented functions, such as below:

```
function areaFunction(radiusParam)
{
    /// <summary>Determines the area of a cicle based on a radius parameter.</summary>
    /// <param name="radius" type="Number">The radius of the circle.</param>
    /// <returns type="Number">Returns a number that represents the area.</returns>
    var areaVal;
    areaVal = Math.PI * radiusParam * radiusParam;
    return areaVal;
}
```

Conceivably you could parse this yourself at run-time, for the presenting documentation at will or supplementing the details of an unhandled exception.

Answer (score 1):

In multi-windowed web applications, if you need to share a function between windows to be executed at a later time, but can't guarantee that the owner of that function (the window it was defined in) will be alive at execution time, you can serialize the function using `toString()`, store it to the pertinent window, and call `eval()` on it at a later time/time of execution. Granted, using `eval()` has its own warts, but this seems like a legitimate use case (we need to reinvoke the script parsing engine to turn the serialized function back into executable code).

This is the only sure-fire way to not get access denied errors in this scenario. The gotcha here is that execution context now becomes the window we are calling `eval()` from, and not the scope that the function was originally defined in, so care must be taken not to rely on variables outside of the function's immediate scope.

Answer (score 0):

Could be used as a way of coding up Web Workers without having to place functions in separate files.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize function stringification to include a function in a generated page with syntax highlighting of the function in the source.
I've done this with CoffeeScript too, with the function written in and highlighted as CoffeeScript, but treated as a JavaScript function since it... is one. Or since it's compiled to one when the rest of the CoffeeScript is compiled.

[See this on github:](https://github.com/1j01/multifiddle/blob/c1a66755fcdec7ec1b0ede232ed4086bda1dcf99/panes.coffee#L176-L200)

```
        error_handling = ->
            d = document.createElement "div"
            d.className = "error bubble script-error"
            window.onerror = (error)->
                document.body.appendChild d
                d.style.position = "absolute"
                d.style.borderRadius = d.style.padding = 
                d.style.bottom = d.style.right = "5px"
                d.innerText = d.textContent = error

        body += """
            <script>~#{error_handling}()</script>
            <style>
                .error {
                    color: red;
                }
                .error.bubble {
                    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
                    color: white;
                }
                body {
                    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
                }
            </style>
        """
```

Answer (score 0):

### assert arg not null

```
exports.warnNull = function() {
  var func = arguments.callee.caller
  var args = func.toString().match(/function\s*\w*\((.*?)\)\s*/)[1].split(',').map(Function.prototype.call.bind(String.prototype.trim))
  var params = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
  for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i ++) {
    if (!params[i]) {
      console.warn(gutil.colors.yellow('缺少变量 : ' + args[i]))
    }
  }
}
```

### wrap long String

```
exports.controller = function(){
/*
app.controller('{{ controllerName }}', function({{ injects }}) {
  // ...
})
*/
}.toString().slice(16, -4)
```

Answer (score 0):

`toString` is a serializer method. In some cases, we need to store function logic to storage such as database or transport via internet. It's also a kind of data to describe 'how to do something'.