# How to see a delegate's source code or encapsulating method when debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[So in JavaScript, you can call toString() on a function to return it's source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327668/calling-tostring-on-a-javascript-function-returns-source-code). However, no such construct exists for C# delegates.

Let's say I have this code sample here:

```
void DoThing()
{
    Console.WriteLine("I did a thing");
}

void Execute(Action act)
{
    act();
}

public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    Execute(DoThing);
    Execute(() => Console.WriteLine("llama lambda"));
}
```

If I debug this code in Visual Studio 2019, and put a breakpoint on `Execute`, I can look at the properties of `act`.

For the first call with `DoThing`, Visual Studio can at least give me the name of the method and it's return type (`Void DoThing()`), but *not* the source code. If I have multiple `DoThing`s in my source code, this will not be very helpful at all.

But for the lambda, I get no useful info in the debugger (`{Method = {Void <Process>b__11_0()}}`).

Now, of course in this small example code, it is pretty easy to find the functions by just retracing the call stack, but in some cases, this is a very long and arduous endeavour, especially when it needs to be done multiple times.

I searched around on google and I couldn't find a simple answer to this question, or even find anywhere where this question was asked:

**Is there any way to find the source code of a delegate in C# when using the Visual Studio debugger (without just retracing the call stack)?**

If yes, *how?*

And if no, *why*?

Comment: Visual studio is displaying something like `act.Method.Name`, you could watch `act.Method.DeclaringType.Name`, but lamda's are compiled into a generated type (eg https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAExAagD4AEBMBGAsAKHQGYACLEgYRIG8CT6yAWEgUQA8BTAYwFcAXDgAp02TCQhc+ASjoNa+BovGTBUgNyz6AXwKaypdMwCyqmnsXtu/IaYC8APjLYAnIIBEAGw8RIJb2GAECDcpdT0dfC0gA==)

Comment: @JeremyLakeman This information is useful, but it doesn't necessarily explain _why_ I can't see the source code of the function. Even if the lambda gets compiled like that, it still **runs code,** which I could potentially see. If the compiler knows what code to run, surely it could show it to me, right?

Comment: There probably is a way to use `MemberInfo.MetadataToken` to locate debug information and then the relevant source code. Visual Studio *could* use that, but doesn't. Since you can use the debugger to step into a method, is this missing feature going to be valuable to developers? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/suggest-a-feature?view=vs-2019)