# Inject javascript into object function

Tags: javascript

I have an object function like this:

```
var batman = function () {
    this.constructor.prototype.go = function(params){
        ......
    }
}
```

When calling batman.go() I'm passing an object in with a few keys such as:

```
{
    a:1,
    b:2,
    action:function(){..code to scan and inject into...}
}
```

My question is, how do I in batman.go() function, scan through the input param function code of **'action'** and if a match is found, inject code into a certain place.

The code I am looking for is:

```
history.pushState({name:'homepage'},null,uri);
```

I want to inject so it looks like this:

```
history.pushState({id:an_id_variable,name:'homepage'},null,uri);
```

What is being inserted is:

```
id:an_id_variable
```

Comment: If i understood you corectly: I don't think it can be done without using `eval()` function which is a huge security risk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are some real world uses for function.toString()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356283/what-are-some-real-world-uses-for-function-tostring)

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski there is no security for your code in the browser. `eval()` is a toy compared to what the developer console can do.

Comment: so if i use eval how can that be done? the actual scan and replacement/injection. 
And what security risk could that create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`function.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) to get the source of `params.action`, [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to find and replace occurences of the snippet in question, and then the [`Function()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) constructor to dynamically create a new function with the amended source code:

```
var batman = function () {
    this.constructor.prototype.go = function(params){
        ...
        let newAction = new Function(params.action.toString().replace(
            /history\.pushState\({name:'homepage'},null,uri\);/g,
            `history.pushState({id:${an_id_variable},name:'homepage'},null,uri);`
        ));
        //use newAction() however you like
    }
}
```

It should be noted that if any end user has any amount of control over the content that can go in `params.action`, this would allow for completely arbitrary code injection by that user - but as pointed out in comments, arbitrary code can already be run on browsers via developer console. Just be aware of the security implications of a solution like this.

Also note that using the Function constructor binds the function to the global scope and it will lose any `this` context. You can bind it to an appropriate `this` context with `function.bind()` like this:

```
newAction = newAction.bind(params.bindTarget);
```

Then, when newAction executes, whatever params.bindTarget references will be `this`.

Comment: This looks like exactly what i need thank you. your last note regarding 'this', I might need it, can i pass in a copy/reference ?

Comment: Sure, you can just pass in whichever object the function should be bound to and store the return value of `newAction.bind(params.bindTarget)` and do as you wish with it.

Comment: bind is totally new to me and im not sure im following, would it be too much to ask you to add a sample to your answer?

Comment: I'd be happy to, but I've been making several assumptions about what you're actually going to be doing with the new function. Is storing it in a variable sufficient?

Comment: Yes, storing it in a variable is enough. the "old" action includes  some xhr code, that shall be executed. but before that, i need to inject this ID into the pushstate parameter, i dont want to have to do it manually in "old action" because the batman object is going to be reused many times for different pages, hence why i want to automate the process. I need the ID in pushstate so i later at another part of the code can locate said ID to match a popstate.

Comment: Two questions: 1. Whats with the ${...} for the variable?, and 2. Im getting this error: Function statements require a function name
    at new Function

Comment: @Jason 1. I assumed that you would want to insert the value contained in `an_id_variable` into the new function code, so I used an ES6 [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to accomplish that easily. It's equivalent to `"history.pushState({id:" + an_id_variable + ",name:'homepage'},null,uri);"`

2. From the error it seems like you're just writing the `new Function(...)` part as a standalone statement, without assigning it to anything or calling it, which can never be valid, it must be stored or used somehow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203627/discussion-between-jason-and-klaycon).

Comment: @Jason Apologies, I'm currently on a network that is unable to connect to SO's chat site. I can hop on in a few hours if you'd like a more real time exchange to clarify the answer.

Comment: thhats much appreciiated. ill be here for 3 more hours. thank you!

Comment: I got it to work, but it loses the event parameter when convert to string, so stuck again. This issue is getting too complicated and messy, so i will abandon it and go with my previous working solution. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: That's reasonable, solutions involving dynamically editing code are rarely clean or really desirable. Best of luck with the rest of your project!